# Adding a base64 encoded image as a attachment in mailto()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, canvas, mailto

I am using a Canvas on which user draws.
And i do have a E-Mail link beside it
I want that when the E-Mail is clicked the canvas is coverted in to image and that image is to be e-mailed as a attachment.

So far i've converted the canvas in to image using

`var image = canvas.toDataURL();`
It gives a base64 encoded image.

On E-Mail link
`<a href="mailto:abc@domain.com?subject=my report&body=see attachment&attachment="image" ">E-Mail</a>`

But this gives me the base64 encoded string in the body of the mail.

Is there any way out to attach the image as a attachment in mail using javascript,php,jquery or anything else??

Comment: You'll be able to do this server side using PHP, .NET, Ruby, Python, etc. But I doubt you'll be able to do that client side for security reasons.

Comment: @Steven its ok ..i am open to server side solution also if you can give me some solid solution..but i want only to embed that as a attachment in mailto.

Comment: you can try to send html email using `<img src="data:image/png;<BASE64>"/>`

Comment: @jcubic i want to get the image attached in the e-mail client of the machine..either outlook or whichever the user is using.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to do something server side to make this work.  My advice would go something like this:

1. The user clicks the email link/button which pushes the image data up to the server.
2. On the server side, the image data gets saved in to a temporary file.
3. The temporary file is attached to an email and delivered to the user.
4. The temporary file is then deleted.

As for how you'd specifically go about doing this...I think most of the steps are intuitive, but you're going to need some way to easily mail the attachment.  There are a lot of solutions for that, but if you don't mind some shameless self-promotion, have a look at my PHP mail script:

https://github.com/stlewis/Mail

It's super easy to use and it supports attachments of all types.

Comment: I have tried this thing but it won't serve my use case..as there is no way i can  use active directory in php mail() function.SO need some solution that is just similar to mailto() function.